# How to do Database changes after user exit from the website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

i have a rental website and when someone wants to make an offer he has 7 min to pay, if he wont pay the offer will delete.

i have a timer on my form to check the time, and when the timer is on 0:00 and the  user didn't pay his offer will delete.

MY question is  how can i check if user log out? i mean user can exit from the site (by clicking X) and his session will end. 
i want to delete his rent offer if user quit from the website.

Thanks for the helpers.

Comment: You can capture the window unload event in script and perform some action upon that.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the reservations that are too old on your server? That keeps you from writing tons of frontside code. Like: how to delete the offer if the user goes offline and there is no way to contact the server to remove the reservation?

Comment: How can i check if the reservations are too old?

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario, I don't think its a good idea to rely on browser events, such as `onunload` & `onbeforeunload`. User may have opened more than one tabs. So closing one tab will remove the offer. Furthermore, if the user click back button these events will be fired. So don't rely on browser events for this.

(But, if the user clicked on LogOut then you have enough information to delete the offer.)

Perhaps you can use following approach to handle your original problem:

1. When user create a new offer store these details in the database with two extra columns: `OfferCreatedUtcDateTime` and `PaymentCompleted`(which should be `false`).
2. If the user completed payment successfully, you can set `PaymentCompleted` to `true`.
3. Then you can use one of the following two options:

Option 1:
Create a [windows service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/) which will check above database columns. If the `PaymentCompleted == false` and `OfferCreatedUtcDateTime + offer valid period > CurrentUtcDateTime` then you can delete this offer.

Option 2:
As mentioned by @nvoigt in the answer, every time user search for a resource you can ignore or delete offers which satisfies the condition mentioned in Option 1.

Hope this helps.

Comment: if user clicked on logout button it easy to delete his offers. but how can i delete his offer after he click on X / his User Session end?

Comment: What Do you think about this idea- " , i can save in my database the time that the user did his offer. when user wants to make an offer i will do that check (if user hasnt pay about his rent i will delete it and the dates will be available). is it a good idea?"

Answer (score 0):

First do not fulfill offers that are older than your timeout(7mins) I'm assuming that you have OfferCreatedDate timeStamp. Second create a job that will clean all unfulfilled and expired offers. Hope this helps

Comment: Can i add a query that will automatic delete those offer?, i have to fulfill the offer because i  want to give to user priority to the dates and the car

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Not reliably. The user will not send you a nice message when he does not do something.

You can program your site to send you a signal if something *happens*, but you need to know when something *doesn't* happen. And it can "not happen" in multiple ways, many of them not allowing a signal to be transmitted.

Just imagine your user's train goes into a tunnel or he kills his browser, his computer crashes or cell phone loses battery power. All events that happen daily and all of them will *not* notify you nicely. They cannot.

So what you need to do is figure out a way to delete all obsolete orders. Either on a timer in an independent service, or maybe before a user places any order. But you need do that in a place independent of the user playing nice with your frontend app.

---

One way of handling this would be to save the date and time of creation with every offer you give out. Every time you check available resources and create a new offer for a user, delete all offers that are older than your limit before giving out new offers, thereby freeing up the blocked resources.

Comment: Do you have any idea how can i make it?  i tried a lot of things.. Also i have to save his offer and to give him 7 min because he has priority of the car and the dates..

Comment: i read your edit and i have an idea, i can save in my database the time that the user did his offer. when user wants to make an offer i will do that check (if user hasnt pay about his rent i will delete it and the dates will be available). is it a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

What about not focusing on how to set the timer to 0 when user session end but check other users timer's when another user create one ?

Then you can still have the checking process for the connected user, when it goes to 0 it stopped but for the case the user close the windows or leave, when another user create a reservation you also and firstly check if there's timer still alive older than 7 minutes and you release them so the user currently doing a reservation can do this one that has just been set as available ?

Comment: How can i do it? i mean how to check other user's timer?

Comment: When your user wants to make a rental, he first have to select which "product" he want right ? Then at the moment you get the list from your database to give it to the user screen, you just create a little function that will check in your database every offer and unlock products locked since more than 7 minutes. And then you just delete offers older than 7 minutes.